# Prepopulate username based on link clicked in email

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm sending users an email. In this email they must click a link that brings them to the login page of my site:
www.testsite/login

I'd like the username(Email address) to be prepopulated for them.

I was thinking of simply adjusting the link sent to them to include it like so:
www.testsite/login?email=tester@test.com

I can then use some javascript to pull this info and place it in the form field.

I'd like people thought's on this approach.
Is it safe? Is there a better or easier way to achieve it? Is there any problems with this approach?

My app uses grails 1.3.7 by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Cookie is a lot safer .. Otherwise a session.. Why do you want to show it in Query string

Comment: Instead of using javascript to prepopulate the input, why not do it server side?

Comment: absolutely server side. If you can send them an email, then you can generate a unique ID of some sort. Put that ID in the query string and then look that id up and then put the email in the form from the server.

Comment: Ok.....I've left out some vital info. I'm not actually sending the email from my server. An admin user click's a link on my 'admin' app. This app then open's the user's default email client and prepopulates with 'to','subject' and 'body' which contains the link to click. The admin user then sends the email from their email client. The person in the 'To' fields receive the email and they click the link! It's this user's email that I want prepopulated in the consumer app.

Comment: You can stil do it on the server side.  When they click the link in the email, it should hit a controller which can grab the email, put in request scope, then render your form with the email populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it would probably be better to pre-populate it on the server side, here is a modification of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1721527) on Stack Overflow:

```
function getEmailFromUrl(){
   var regexS = "[\\?#&]email=([^&#]*)";
   var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
   var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
   if(results == null) return "";
   else return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then, use that the result of that function to populate the textbox:

```
document.getElementById('email_address').value=getEmailFromUrl();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For those of you who are wondering where `decodeURIComponent` comes from, it is actually a native JavaScript function. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp.